# how to remove Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

For this link i opened and copy from the code and paste for my page but its not working iam getting this error Uncaught ReferenceError: PhotoSwipe is not defined....check this linkhttp://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM

Answer (score 0):

Add next strings inside your `<head>` tag

```
<script src="http://photoswipe.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://photoswipe.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js"></script>
```

You can find them in pen's `Settings`.